# Teradata error 2641 <tablename> was restructured. Resubmit

Tags: teradata

I have a table that I drop and create an index each day and I have another job that queries this table with an `ACCESS` lock.
Sometimes these jobs happen at the same time and then I get the following error:

`2641 %DBID.%TVMID was restructured. Resubmit.`

I have read in the documentation the following:

```
Explanation:
A table was changed before a statement that references the table was processed.
(For example, an index may have been added or a field removed.)

Notes:
The statement may not have the intended result because of the change in the table.

Remedy:
Examine the table and resubmit the request.
```

https://docs.teradata.com/reader/8MhLDQBmL52OycrEKPuGqg/Ju5pqm9uRFO6VziQdcmA6w

I guess this is because the `CREATE INDEX` sentence requests an `EXCLUSIVE` lock and the `SELECT` sentence is queued while the index is created, but when the `SELECT` is poped from the queue the table has a different version number and it fails.

Maybe I am completely wrong but,
Is there anyway to avoid this behaviour? 
Something in the way of making the `SELECT` sentence reevaluate when it gets the chance to get executed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the application to handle the 2641 and resubmit the request. There is no option to have the database do so automatically.